# How to resolve procedure or function which was not supplied?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this issue and not sure how to resolve this?

When I click on "Top Locations" in my webpage I get the following error:

```
Procedure or function 'sp_um_getTopLocations' expects parameter '@year', which was not supplied.
```

This is the code where I get the error message:

```
 public void getTopLocations()
{
    try
    {
        string strQuery = "EXEC sp_um_getTopLocations '500'";
        ds = DataControl.GetDataSet(strQuery);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            gvTopLocations.DataSource = ds;
            gvTopLocations.DataBind();

            gvTopLocations.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
            gvTopLocations.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
        }
        else
        {
            ds.Dispose();
            gvTopLocations.DataSource = ds;
            gvTopLocations.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toastr.ShowToast(ex.Message, "Error", Toastr.Type.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        //ds.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I am not sure ho to resolve and would like some assistance please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes for this exception:

- Number of supplied and expected parameters may not be matching.
- Types of supplied and expected parameters may not be matching.

You should check you procedure parameters with your supplied parameters from the code side.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like 'sp_um_getTopLocations' needs @year parameter.
Try this:

```
string strQuery = "EXEC sp_um_getTopLocations '500' 2019";
```

Or

`string strQuery = "EXEC sp_um_getTopLocations 2019";`

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.  I went to look at the stored procedure and found:

```
DECLARE @year_TEMP  varchar(10)
DECLARE @month_TEMP varchar(10)

IF(@year = '0') SET @year_TEMP = REPLACE(@year,'0','') + '%'
ELSE SET @year_TEMP = @year

IF(@month = '0') SET @month_TEMP = REPLACE(@month,'0','') + '%'
ELSE SET @month_TEMP    = @month
```

So in my query I changed it to:

```
string strQuery = "EXEC sp_um_getTopLocations '500','0','0'";
```

Now its all working as expected.

Thanks